# irritating TortoiseSVN error - file or directory is corrupted and chkdsk at boot

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-7-x64

> Can't move 'D:\Documents\Websites\blah.svn\tmp\entries' to 'D:\ ... .svn\entries': The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

Any thoughts on what would cause this?  This usually happens when trying to commit a large number of new files.  Sometimes an update fixes it but most of the time I have to delete the offending directory, re-download it, and attempt to add or update it again.

EDIT: it seems my pc always wanting to chkdsk as boot is related.

Comment: Why do you guys want to close this? sure it could maybe go on Super User but cmon, StackOverflow has way more people that actually use this. It has enough to do with programming to stay here I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From ServerFault:

This is a known bug in Window 7, slated to be fixed in SP 1:

http://subversion.wandisco.com/blogs/windows-7-bogus-errorfilecorrupt-error-.html

Comment: Oh I wish i could +1 you again...  That explains why just about every time I restart my pc It wants to check my hard drive...  I've been worried it was going to fail on me.

Comment: I have SP1 and still had this problem... anyone else?

Answer (score 2):

The workaround, until this Windows 7 bug isn't fixed: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#cantmove2