# Can I simulate disk errors using software or programming so chkdsk will return errors during testing?

Tags: windows, simulator

I'm trying to test some software that interfaces with chkdsk, interprets the results, and displays something to the user. I want to test scenarios where chkdsk returns errors but I'm having a hard time getting into these scenarios as all the hard drives I have access to do not report any drive errors.

Is there a way to force a disk to have errors either by "ruining" the drive by running some software or code that will mess it up? Is there a trick I can do to get chkdsk to return some errors so I can see what the error output looks like in a repeatable way?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Simply suggestion: Use chkdsk in a virtualized Windows install.  Then, with the virtual machine shut down, you can make any changes you like to the virtual disk file.  Or are you asking about I/O errors, as opposed to metadata corruption?

Comment: @Adriano: The mock `chkdsk`'s messages won't be very accurate without detailed information about the real messages.  And if he had that, he wouldn't need the mock.

Comment: @Adriano: Hmm, "so I can see what the error output looks like" suggests the opposite to me.  But you could be right.

Comment: @BenVoigt you're right I didn't read until the end! :) **Brian** in this case I suggest you use [this tool](http://www.amazon.com/Stanley-51-621-16-Ounce-Fiberglass-Hammer/dp/B000VSMJCS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1383667661&sr=8-1&keywords=hammer) on your hard disk to produce a true and repeatable chkdsk error output.

Comment: I cannot use a mock unfortunately because like Adriano said if I had that output I would already have what I need. I'm just the tester on this and not the developer. BTW testing and developing go together ... unless you are using waterfall LOL

Comment: @Adriano, let me go get my hammer now ...

Comment: I'm hoping there might be some software trick I could do that would cause chkdsk errors to occur. Working in a VM environment is ideal.

Comment: @BrianTHannan I am getting chkdsk errors regularly, and now believe that TortoiseSVN on Windows 7 may generate these errors, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049501/irritating-tortoisesvn-error-file-or-directory-is-corrupted-and-chkdsk-at-boot) - not reliably of course otherwise the sysadmin guys here would be able to determine it, without reinstalling the OS.